# How do I click on the href link?

Tags: python, html, selenium, href

I have tried using driver.find_element_by_id // link_text // partial link text , what should I be using to access this href. I am getting the No Such Element Exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated tysm.

```html
    
<a href="../s-reminderNotice.asp?fname=b%2D3c%2DpLessonBooking%2Easp%3Flimit%3Dpl" 
class="sidelinkbold" target="mainFrame" onmouseover=" 
window.status='Practical Training Booking'; return true" onmouseout="window.status=' '; 
return true">Booking without Fixed Instructor</a>
```

SOLVED; ELEMENT WAS IN AN IFRAME ; HAD TO SWITCH FRAME TO ACCESS ELEMENT

Comment: what exception are u getting ?

Comment: The No Such Element Exception ; ive edited it into the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='YOUR LINK']")).click();
```

Comment: I've tried this but to no avail ; is it not possible to access a link without an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below WebElement then click on it:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Booking without Fixed Instructor')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("sidelinkbold").click()
```

It has a simple class name you can use to click on.

Comment: that wouldn't work as there is a whole column to the left of the website which is under the same class

Comment: Then the below answer as an xpath would work.